# p:barChart y axis format

Tags: charts, primefaces, jqplot

I use primefaces 4.0 barchart, but i want to modify some default proprieties. This is my xhtml page

```
 <p:barChart  id="chart" value="#{marchebean.model}" legendPosition="ne" xaxisLabel="Année" yaxisLabel="Montant en DT" title="Factures payés par années" />
```

What i want to do

1.I want to separate  between hundreds , thousands and millions in y axis by a space i.e changing the format of my numbers , i use `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(mynumber);` in java but i don't know how to achieve this with charts in primefaces.

2. I want to display on the top of every bar the value  setted in backing bean and change it's size.

**Edit**

Separation between thousand done, but i still don't know how display values above every bar or change their size. this is my new code

```
 <p:barChart  id="chart" value="#{marchebean.model}"  extender="ext"  style="height:600px;" legendPosition="ne" xaxisLabel="Année" yaxisLabel="Montant en DT" title="Factures payés par années" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function ext() {
    this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
        formatString: "%'i"
    };
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults={
             renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels:{show:true}

    },

    $.jqplot.sprintf.thousandsSeparator = ' ';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### First question

You can fulfill your need #1 using an extender.
Here's the related excerpt from Primefaces' manual regarding extenders:

> 3.14.15 Extender Chart API provide high level access to commonly used jqplot options however there are many more customization options
>   available in jqplot. Extender feature provide access to low level apis
>   to do advanced customization by enhancing the configuration object,
>   here is an example to increase shadow depth of the line series where
>   model's extender property is set to "ext".
>
> ```
> <p:chart type="line" model="#{bean.model}" />
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> function ext() {
> //this = chart widget instance
> //this.cfg = options
> this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
> shadowDepth: 5
> };
> }
> ```
>
> Refer to jqPlot docs for available options.

Note: in Primefaces 4.0, the extender function name is provided as an attribute of the component tag, eg. `<p:barChart extender="ext" .../>`

To use whitespaces as thousands separator, use the following extender:

```
function ext() {
    this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
        formatString: "%'i"
    };

    $.jqplot.sprintf.thousandsSeparator = ' ';
}
```

### Second question

You will also manage to do it making some tweaking in your extender.
For example, the following piece of configuration will display values above every bar:

```
  seriesDefaults: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      pointLabels:{show:true}
  },
```

And just use some CSS to change the size!

--
Zim

Comment: thousandsSeparator works like a charm ... please take a look at the modified question..

Comment: You might need to add the `jqplot.pointLabels.js` file in your project.
You will find it on the [jqplot repo](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/src), browsing to src/plugins.

Comment: Any update? Could you please inform other Stackovernauts whether you successfully added values above bars or not?

Comment: well i added `jqplot.pointLabels.js` under css folder and added the following line to my code  `<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/css/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>`     **Result :** The char disappeared!!

Comment: Could you try without  `renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer`?

Comment: Well, in my answer I suggested to add explicitly the renderer, now I'm asking you to try **without** it ;)
Anyway, doesn't your browser developer console tell you anything about the disappearing?

Comment: Aww sorry  ... i tried without it but it's not working , java script is telling me   `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
chart.xhtml:143 Uncaught ReferenceError: ext is not defined` , i think there is a problem with the way i'am using `seriesDefaults: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      pointLabels:{show:true}
  },`

Comment: You have a trailing comma in  `seriesDefaults` that should be a semicolon, maybe it will help